# Support Async Linq operations in custom IQueryProvider

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, c#-8.0

I have a custom implementation of `IQueryProvider` and `IQueryable` and I have to provide support to an async operation. I want to provide a method such as `ToArrayAsync` to singleAsync etc, but I am confused.

For sync methods all is provide by `System.Linq.Queryable` class but for async nothing seems available.

I found `System.Linq.Async.Queryable` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) that points to this repository: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive, owned by dot net.

Should I add a reference to this package and implement `IAsyncQueryable` and `IAsyncQueryProvider` as I did for the sync version of `IQueryable`?

Is this the official way?

Comment: I advise you to implement the built-in [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.iasyncenumerable-1.getasyncenumerator?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Thanks Aluan, Actually i already implemented IAsyncEnumerable to provide some custom async extensions, this means i have to write my customs extensions methods also for ToArrayAsync, FirstOrDefault etc.? No framework support for this?

Comment: Yeah you've got to implement these yourself but it's easy. `public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) { var results = new List<T>();  await foreach (var element in source) results.Add(element); return results;`

Comment: Or the more generic version, `private static async Task<TCollection> ToCollectionAsync<T, TCollection>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) where TCollection: new(), ICollection<T> { var results = new TCollection(); await foreach (var element in source) results.Add(element); return results; }` and then `public static Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) => ToCollectionAsync<T, List<T>>(source);`, `public static Task<HashSet<T>> ToHashSetAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) => ToCollectionAsync<T, HashSet<T>>(source);`, and so on for each collection type you want

Comment: I am not at my pc now, but if i do like this i can not use this extensions after a where call that returns an IQueryable, not?

Comment: Yes you can but I made a mistake. The extension message need to take an `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: Thanks, I will try but honestly I am worried about this approach, if someone also to my library have a reference to entityframeworkcore or something similar an ambiguity may happen on wich extensions calls

Comment: Yes. That's a very good point. If you're building a library, I wouldn't expose these to consumers. You might want  to put them in a dedicated package